# Marketing Cloud SMS expiration time

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, sms

I send sms from Journey builder. If I answer SMS within the hour for a keyword, the response will come. If I answer after a couple of hours, then the answer to the keyword will be "There was an error processing your message.". I think it's because the response is timed out or something like that. How can it be extended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the limits on '**[MobileConnect Conversation Windows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.mc_moc_conversation_windows.htm)**'. The default given for time between send and response is 60 minutes I believe, but you can change the configuration to a shorter or longer time. These are set at a Keyword level.

**[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_configure_conversation_window.htm&type=5)** is the documentation on configuring a MobileConnect Conversation Window.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful for me!